# Are there any visualization tools to realize the hierarchical style of the SQL query data as an output result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows

I guess should be some visualization tools (MS SQL Server) to represent some hierarchical style of the SQL query data as an output result.

I just have some hierarchical table chain with 7 tables and I have to query 1-2nd level of it very often in order to check the bottom of this chain as well as some intermediate tables.

Any clue guys?

Thank you in advance!

P.S. It would be cool if MS SQL Management Studio could accept some plugins in its next generation... :)

Comment: http://www.razorsql.com/

Comment: @reggie Well... Can you share any screenshot to check how it looks, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brad Schulz has a pretty amazing proc (usp_DrawTree) here:
http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2010/04/t-sql-tuesday-005-reporting.html

Here is one of his example outputs:

```
/*
                               ┌───────────┐  
                               │   Anne    │
                             ┌─┤ Dodsworth │ Sales Representative
                             │ │  Ext452   │
                             │ └───────────┘  
                ┌──────────┐ │
                │  Steven  │ │
              ┌─┤ Buchanan ├─┤ Sales Manager
              │ │ Ext3453  │ │
              │ └──────────┘ │
              │              │ ┌────────┐  
              │              │ │ Robert │
              │              ├─┤  King  │ Sales Representative
              │              │ │ Ext465 │
              │              │ └────────┘  
              │              │ ┌─────────┐  
              │              │ │ Michael │
              │              └─┤ Suyama  │ Sales Representative
              │                │ Ext428  │
              │                └─────────┘  
              │ ┌──────────┐  
              │ │  Laura   │
              ├─┤ Callahan │ Inside Sales Coordinator
              │ │ Ext2344  │
              │ └──────────┘  
  ┌─────────┐ │
  │ Andrew  │ │
  │ Fuller  ├─┤ Vice President, Sales
  │ Ext3457 │ │
  └─────────┘ │
              │ ┌─────────┐  
              │ │  Nancy  │
              ├─┤ Davolio │ Sales Representative
              │ │ Ext5467 │
              │ └─────────┘  
              │ ┌───────────┐  
              │ │   Janet   │
              ├─┤ Leverling │ Sales Representative
              │ │  Ext3355  │
              │ └───────────┘  
              │ ┌──────────┐  
              │ │ Margaret │
              └─┤ Peacock  │ Sales Representative
                │ Ext5176  │
                └──────────┘  
*/
```

Comment: Thank you! This SQL Store Procedure is pretty interesting! And I agree it does some good job. But I prefer some tool where I can collapse some tables within a chain and etc.

Comment: Ah, I see. Perhaps you could query using FOR XML, and use any number of XML tools to do so.  This may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345137(v=sql.90).aspx#forxml2k5_topic8

Comment: Yeah... I know it... I am lazy a little bit so I guess when I do some query of the 1st level table the tool should be smart and build up the complete hierarchy for me, hehehe :) ...And also when table changes I have re-write that FOR XML SQL everytime.. That's is not good at all.

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle anyway (i got here via SQL tag), you can use lpad with the associated level to format the output (similar to an expanded folder view, deeper levels have more indentation):

```
SELECT LEVEL,
    LPAD(' ', 2 * LEVEL - 1) || first_name || ' ' ||
    last_name AS employee
   FROM employee
   START WITH employee_id = 1
   CONNECT BY PRIOR employee_id = manager_id;
```